# TestFlight "The requested app is not available or doesn't exist." Error shows on downloading new build

Tags: ios, react-native, testing, testflight

I have been working on an app from last 8 months and we are testing it through TestFlight recently all of our previous builds turned into expired automatically (which is strange) even though the 90 days testing period for most of the builds was not passed.

And earlier this week we pushed another build to TestFlight which processed successfully but after a few hours of deployment it automatically turned into expired and after that, no tester was able to download it.

To fix it we pushed a couple of new builds to TestFlight by just bumping up the build versions, although now these two build didn't turn into expired but now all the testers are not able to download these from TestFlight and it prompts a message that "this requested app is not available or doesn't exist"

We are not sure if it's an error from our side or from apple.

Comment: please check your email that is connected to app store. your app has missing something. For Me in was missing some things and after uploading successfully to testflight the build was disappeared from testflight

Comment: I am facing this issue from last one and half week, and we didn't receive any email from apple's side. Also, we tried to contact them through support, but that didn't work as it's a so slow process. Currently, our main issue is the testers are not able to download the build from TestFlight.